# Visibility of web.config in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, web-config

Who can see the web.config of a site?

Comment: @ClarkKent, that is not the same question as this one.

Comment: @ClarkKent, I think the question is about th visibility of web.config in and of itself, not how to use it to block access to other pages.

Answer (score 1):

Anyone with access to the server's file system can view web.config. Over the internet, though,
web.config is blocked.

It is inaccessible over the internet for security reasons.

If you look at `%windir%\system32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config` (the base config for the entire machine), you'll see `<add fileExtension=".config" allowed="false" />`. So by default, IIS is blocked from serving any file with the .config extension.